# SQL group by and listing

Tags: sql, list, group-by

I have the following information in DB :

```
id | name     | company
---+----------+------
 1 | Joe      | company_1
 2 | Sally    | company_2
 3 | Marc     | company_3
 4 | Bob      | company_1
```

Is possible to do something like that in SQL :

```
SELECT company, _something_ FROM my_db GROUP BY company
```

And get :

```
 company   | members
---------- | ---------
 company_1 | Joe, Bob
 company_2 | Sally
 company_3 | Marc
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(MySQL)/LISTAGG(Oracle)/XML+STUFF(SQL Server)/string_agg(Postgresql)` choose depending on RDBMS and search SO. This question is obvious duplicate

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT company, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ',') AS members FROM my_table GROUP BY company
```